# Select a Random Product for every 20 products in a collection

Tags: magento, collections

Here is My Code,

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
            ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(500))
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
$collection->setPageSize(20);
```

Because of this i'm getting Random 20 Products but i want it should give One Product from 1st 20 products, One Product from 2nd 20 products... 20products.

How do i make this ?

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that something like this should help you, good luck =D

```
<?php
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
            ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(500))
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
    $collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
    $collection->setPageSize(20);

    $array = array();
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $array[] = $product->getId();   
    }
    $rand = rand(0,19);
    do {
        $rand2 = rand(0,19);
    } while ($rand2 == $rand);

    $produc1 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($array[$rand]);
    $produc2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($array[$rand2]); 
?>
```